# Subscribing a variable in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular6, observable

In my component, I subscribe to a variable like this:

```
import { Subject, of } from 'rxjs'

....
distance: number
constructor() {
    this.distance = 0;
    this.getDistance().subscribe(
      (newDistanceValue) => {
        console.log('newDistanceValue', newDistanceValue)
      }
    )
    ....
}

getDistance(): Observable<number> {
   return of(this.distance);
}
```

I get the following output, for the initial value of the variable.

```
newDistanceValue 0
```

...but when I change the value in other methods of the component, subscriber doesn't output the new value of distance.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rxjs not rsjx :)

you're generating a new Observable every time you call `getDistance`, and it only emits one value which is the current value of `distance`, you should make it a `BehaviorSubject` instead

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'

....
distance$ = new BehaviorSubject(0)
constructor() {
    this.distance$.subscribe(
      (newDistanceValue) => {
        console.log('newDistanceValue', newDistanceValue)
      }
    )
    // or get value of distance synchronously
    console.log(this.distance$.getValue())
    ....
}

foo() {
    this.distance$.next(1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try.